# How to pass arguments when extending a jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, extend, argument-passing

I'm trying to modify `.offset()` so that it never returns `undefined`, i.e. for invisible/hidden elements.

The problem that I'm having with that is that I don't know how to properly pass `this` to the original method, to be honest. Breakpoint-debugging reveals that I keep getting `Window` when it should be the element in question. Here's what I got:

```
(function( $ ){
  var original = $.fn.offset;

  $.fn.offset = function( elem, coordinates, pass ) {
    console.log('step 1');   // successful.
    console.log(this);       // element confirmation.
    var o = original(elem, coordinates, pass);  // triggers an exception.
    console.log('step 2');   // is never reached.

    if (o === undefined ) {
      console.log('step 3a');
      return {};
    }
    else {
      console.log('step 3b');
      return o;
    }
  }
}( jQuery ));

[…]

$('#element').offset();   // method call.
```

And here's the exception:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.extend.offset (chrome-extension://…/js/jquery-1.11.0.js:10109:10)
    at $.fn.offset (chrome-extension://…/js/jquery-modifications.js:35:11)
```

I've tried different variations – `original(arguments)`, `this.original()`, `original(this, …)` – but none worked. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506156/how-to-edit-a-jquery-function) an argument called `elem` is used next to three more arguments – but I'm not sure why. Is it because the [API](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) mentions `attributeName`, `value` and a callback function? If so then my attempt should work, analogous to the [`.offset()` API](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). Looking at how [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) defines these functions didn't help either because `.fn.attr` doesn't even show up like `.fn.offset` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said:

> The problem that I'm having with that is that I don't know how to properly pass this to the original method, to be honest.

In order to change function scope (this) there are two Function Prototype methods, called `call()` and `apply()`

References to documentation of these two methods:

[Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

So, your code should now looks like this:

```
var original = $.fn.offset;

$.fn.offset = function() {
    var o = original.apply(this, arguments);
    return typeof o === 'undefined' ? {} : o;
};
```

and

```
return typeof o === 'undefined' ? {} : o;
```

It's just a better (IMO) shorter version of:

```
if (typeof o === 'undefined') {
    return {};
} else {
    return o;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but you should explain **why** and **how** it works.

Comment: "It's just a better (IMO) shorter version of […]" « I know, I was just splitting the line for the console logs.